# The Uploaded Image doesn't Save on the database

Tags: php, html, sql

I'am having a button to upload a image and Every time I upload an Image the images doesn't saves on the database and there is no error given,

Here is my Code:

```
<td>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" required>
        <button type="submit" name="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
            Submit
        </button>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['files']))
              {
                $userid = $row['stall_id'];
                $a = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $ab = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $location = "".$a;
                move_uploaded_file($ab, "../pictures/".$location);

                $sql2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stall SET file = ? WHERE stall_id = ?");
                $sql2->execute(array($location,$userid));

            if($sql){                                                   
                echo '
                <script>                                                        
                    window.location = "stalls.php"
                </script>';                                                 
                    }
                    }
                ?>
</td>
```

Comment: does the file actually upload?

Comment: @Dagon it only submits but it doesnt saves on the database.

Comment: yes, but the file, is it uploaded?

Comment: you're using the wrong variable, no idea why you're using `$location = "".$a;`

Comment: and where's this populated from? `$row['stall_id']` - in either case check for errors.

Comment: @Dagon it is uploaded i can see the images on the folder directory, it is not only saving on the database

Comment: @Fred-ii- may code ont that part i think is wrong im just trying some codes,, the table name is stall and its id is stall_id and the entity for the file is file

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php see what that says

Comment: However, you sure you're not trying to do INSERT rather than UPDATE? and saving the filename or as a blob?

Comment: i cant see any `bind_param` statement in your code.

Comment: `if($sql){` that's the wrong variable here btw, should have been `if($sql2){` and add an `else{}` and catch errors. You using mysqli_ or PDO and to connect with? seems like PDO. Mysqli_ needs `bind_param()`. What you have now is PDO syntax `execute(array`

Comment: I also don't see a closing `</form>` tag. Plus `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`. You have errors and some unknowns.

Comment: put after prepare statement     `$sql2->bind_param('si', $location,$userid );  $sql2->execute();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- i will try Insert but what will i insert in the table? so that it will savev the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured it out my self,

```
<td>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="stall_id" value="<?php echo $value['stall_id']?>">
    <button type="submit" name="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
    Submit
    </button>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['files']))
    {
    $userid = $_POST['stall_id'];
    $a = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $ab = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $location = "".$a;
    move_uploaded_file($ab, "../pictures/".$location);

    $sql2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stall SET file = ? WHERE stall_id = ?");
    $sql2->execute(array($location,$userid));

    if($sql2){                                                   
    echo '
    <script>                    
    window.location = "stalls.php"
    </script>';                                                 
    }
    }
    ?>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please Bind Parameter After Prepare  statement. check docs- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
2. in if condition put $update(return value of execution) instead of sql
3. close `</form>` tag.
4. check all variables having data. check with `var_dump()`, `print_r()` or `echo()` methods.

   ```
   <td>
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" required>
     <button type="submit" name="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
       Submit
    </button>
   </form>
   </td>
   <?php
       if(isset($_POST['files']))
         {
           $userid = $row['stall_id'];
           $a = $_FILES['file']['name'];
           $ab = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
           $location = "".$a;
           move_uploaded_file($ab, "../pictures/".$location);

           if( $sql2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stall SET file = ? WHERE stall_id = ?"))
           {

               $sql2->bindParam(1, $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $sql2->bindParam(2, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

               $update=$sql2->execute();
               if($update){                                                   
                    echo '
                    <script>                                                        
                       window.location = "stalls.php"
                    </script>';                                                 
                }
           }else{
               echo 'sql prepare failed';
           }
        }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\VCCDMStry\pages\stalls.php on line 65

Comment: please check `$conn` do u get proper connection?

Comment: yes i have a proper connection i think the problem is that it cannot update the image that has been uploaded the variable a has not been called?

Comment: check the prepare method works correctly ! i edited the code. chek it.

Comment: OP is using `PDO`, not `mysqli`. The binding is done correctly.

Comment: Thanx For your info. @chris85

Answer (score -1):

change from

```
$sql2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stall SET file = ? WHERE stall_id = ?");
$sql2->execute(array($location,$userid));
```

to

```
$sql2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stall SET file = ? WHERE stall_id = ?");
$sql2->bindParam(1, $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql2->bindParam(2, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql2->execute();
```

Comment: Okay, since the update removed the `mysqli` syntax issues I'll remove previous comments. So why are you now limiting the `location` to 12 characters? What was wrong with the OPs code before that you are improving?

Comment: check I m not using 12

Comment: actually we are providing alternate because as per his comment connection was established so no need to check it